# Is it possible to share an Exchange calendar with another outlook user using Thunderbird/Lightning? If so, how?

Tags: 12.04, thunderbird, email, lightning

I am not on a Windows machine and cannot access outlook other than outlook.companyname.com.  I have my exchange email set up through Thunderbird/Lightning AND synced my exchange calendar.

How can I share my exchange calendar with another outlook user?  Thank you.

Comment: When you say share with other outlook user. Do you mean you want share your free/busy status?

Comment: @devav2 - No, I can send event notifications.  I need a specific person to be able to access my calendar at any time on outlook so they can see my schedule for the day/week.

Answer (score 0):

If you have your calender is on outlook.companyname.com, you should be able to **Publish** the calender to anyone you wish to share with.

```
In your calendar, on the Home tab, in the Share group,
click Publish Online, and then click Publish to Office.com.
```

You can also set who can view this calender along with other settings.

Outlook products are being merged (renamed :P) into Office.com so the sources I have below should relate to this.

Sources:
[Share an Outlook calendar with other people](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook-help/share-an-outlook-calendar-with-other-people-HA010354420.aspx#_Toc300732657)
[Publish and share calendars on Office.com](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook-help/publish-and-share-calendars-on-office-com-HA010355570.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

On Thunderbird you can do that with lighting .

If you have already created a local calendar on Thunderbird. First you need to publish your calendar to be shared with others.

To share, Right click on a local calendar -> Select "**Publish Calendar...**". You will get a dialog box prompting to enter the "**Publishing URL**" Enter a proper URL(check with your company email administrator for this URL) It may differ for different companies.
The URL I use is something like http:// domainname\email_ID/EWS/Exchange.asmx